# Removing fields from AWS Cognito user sign in/sign up

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am currently developing an ios mobile app and implementing user sign in/sign up with AWS Cognito. I am having trouble finding information on customizing the sign up/ sign in pages. I want to remove some of the fields from the sign up page because I did not list them as required when I created the User Pool. Can anyone provide some intuition or point me in the right direction for help with this? Thank you.

Comment: Did you find out how to do this? Even I'm looking to remove "sign-up" option from built-in form.

Comment: Ok, I figured out removing signup.

Comment: @Deepthi Can you update your answer with solution please?

Comment: @GirlGeek Honestly, I don't remember now because it's been so long and we stopped using cognito. But I <think> it was something to do with having a custom login screen with custom logo.